# vb.net handle a post with an array

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays, post

I'm trying read an array that was post from a html form

```
<input name="test[]" id="1" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<input name="test[]" id="2" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<input name="test[]" id="3" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<input name="test[]" id="4" type="checkbox" value="4" />
```

In php I know you can just access the data very easily

```
foreach($_POST['test'] as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
```

I've had a look around and haven't come across anything doing the same thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just get `Request("test[]")`, you should get back a comma-separated list of the values.  I'm not sure how well that'd work if the values can have commas in them.

If you need the values as an array, you can check out `Request.Form.GetValues("test[]")`.  It'll probably be null if no boxes were checked, though, so check for that before you use the array.

Comment: Request.Form.GetValues will always return an array of values, regardless of how many items are in that array. So, if you only have 1 input field with the same name, it'll return an array of 1 item. If you have fields that are blank, they'll still be in the array as empty strings.
If you're requesting a field that isn't returned, you'll get [Nothing] as a return value.

Comment: Yep.  If it's posted -- even if it's blank -- it's considered a value.  The one big gotcha is that checkboxes' values aren't posted unless the box is checked.  If none of the boxes are checked, there's no `test[]` in the post, so `GetValues("test[]")` will be about the same as `GetValues("any other non-existent field")`.